# Regex - tagmanager - best way to filter subdirectiory

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a new tagmanager view filter based on regex for a website that has localized languages.
English version is not shown on the URL, but for localized languages, we add /es/ or /pt/ and the ending of the URL is always in the English version.

Pages I want to show for example

```
https://example.com/demo
https://example.com/es/demo
https://example.com/pt/demo
https://example.com/de/demo
https://example.com/features
https://example.com/de/features
https://example.com/pt/features
https://example.com/es/features
```

Pages I do NOT want to show

```
https://example.com/demo1231
https://example.com/demoabc
https://example.com/demo/asdas
https://example.com/features-1231
https://example.com/featuresasaa
```

Advice is welcome.

Comment: The rules are not clear, please expain them.

Comment: What regex engine/programmin language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex, that will match the examples, you have shown (except those that shouldn't match):

```
^https:\/\/example.com\/((es|pt|de)\/)?(demo|features)$
```

You will need to set the `'multiline'` option, if your input span more than one line.

The regex starts from beginning of line, matching the literal string '`https://example.com/`', then followed by an `optional` alternation, either `'es'`, `'pt'`  OR `'de'`, followed by a `slash`. Then it checks for the string either `'demo'` OR `'features'` at the `end of line`.